# How to modify a slice element which is a struct in golang?

Tags: go

You have a golang slice of structs and you would like to change one entry in there.

```
type Type struct {
    value int
}

func main() {

    s := []Type{{0}, {0}}

    // Prints  [{0} {0}]
    fmt.Println(s)

    firstEntry := s[0]
    firstEntry.value = 5

    // Also prints [{0} {0}]
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/32tpcc3-OD

Using the brackets operator and modifying its return does not change the slice itself.

What is the recommended way of doing this slice entry modification ?

Comment: just put it back into the map 
s[0] = firstEntry 
or use a pointer

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Try

```
s[0].value = 5
```

This gets to the backing store of the slice.  Also

```
p := &s[1]
p.value = 6
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also take the address of the slice element directly and de-reference it:

```golang
func main() {

    s := []Type{{0}, {0}}

    // Prints  [{0} {0}]
    fmt.Println(s)

    // De-reference the address of the slice element
    (&s[0]).value = 5

    // Prints [{5} {0}]
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```